# Prefix transformations from OpenCR

Tags: ros-kinetic, opencr, rosserial, turtlebot3, tf-prefix

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run rrt_exploration on my turtlebot3. I need to prefix all per-robot nodes, topics, and transforms with a per-robot name such as "robot_1". I can do this the usual way for all nodes and topics with `<group ns="robot_1">` in my launch file and for almost all transforms with `<param name="tf_prefix", value="robot_1"/>` in the node that provides the transform.

However, this does not work for transforms that are published by the OpenCR via rosserial_python such as `odom`. How can I change the name of the transforms published by the rosserial_python node? Re-flashing the openCR is not an option, as this must be extensible to multi-robot systems.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282214/prefix-transformations-from-opencr/) by [qrfaalnz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33624/qrfaalnz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-02-20**:
How about adding tf_prefix support to rosserial_python, and only the python on the computer would have to be changed?

**Comment by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on 2018-08-01**:
Hello! Did you ever solve this? Having the same issue and the answers to this question were not correct.

**Comment by [qrfaalnz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33624/qrfaalnz/) on 2018-08-01**:
I solved this similarly to @lucasw's comment. Modify rosserial_python to accept a tf_prefix parameter and change Publisher's handlePacket() to add the prefix to child_frame_id and header.frame_id of each tf/tfMessage. Unfortunately I can't post code.

**Comment by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on 2018-08-01**:
Ok! Do you think you could post the code as an answer to my question https://answers.ros.org/question/299330/where-does-turtlebot3_core-define-odom-and-base_footprint-names/ ?

**Comment by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on 2018-08-01**:
or could you perhaps elaborate on where to find Publisher's handlePacket()?

**Comment by [qrfaalnz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33624/qrfaalnz/) on 2018-08-01**:
That is part of rosserial in SerialClient.py. Clone rosserial into your catkin_ws and you should be able to search for it. Look at how other parameters are handled.

**Comment by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) on 2018-08-01**:
TurtleBot3 supports multi-robot application. This link might be help you
http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/applications/#load-multiple-turtlebot3s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package has been updated, now you don't need namespace prefixing for single robot. There is an example launch file (simple.launch) you can check it out.

---

Originally posted by [hasauino](https://answers.ros.org/users/26499/hasauino/) with karma: 91 on 2018-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0